# Displaying last 10 results in pagerank

Tags: matlab

```
% Print the last 10 URLs in page rank order.
[~,id] = sort(x,1,'descend');
fprintf('#     PageRank     Page\n'); 
for j=991:1000
  fprintf('%02d    %1.2e     %s\n',j,x(id(j)),U{id(j)});
end
```

I am trying to print the last ten results in my pagerank function but I do not know which code would be right. The both display results but I do not feel like either is right because I feel like I am missing something.

```
[~,id] = sort(x,1,'ascend');
fprintf('#     PageRank     Page\n'); 
for j=1:10
  fprintf('%02d    %1.2e     %s\n',j,x(id(j)),U{id(j)});
end
```

Comment: Please comment what `x` and `U` are in your code.

Comment: I figured it out actually! but my U is 1000x1 matrix so I doubt you would want to see that

Comment: I don't need to see that.. Your question was to sort `x` and print part of the result and related result on `U`. Thus you need to describe what `x` and `U` are. You can assume some of the users who come to your question understand what PageRank algorithm is and knows what to expect. But you should not expect people to analyze what you *might* mean with those variables.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood then. U is a 1000x1 matrix of webpages collected that contain a certain address within

Comment: Thus `x` is your page rank?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x` is the page rank and `U` is the cell array of names, both results are fine and would give you the entries with the lowest rank. I'd personally go with the `'ascend'` option, just because it's a tiny bit (2.1%) faster on my machine.

Comment: They display different results which wasn't super clear in my post. But I think the ascend option produces the more correct results. However, is my for loop 1:10 correct or should I be doing 991:1000 with ascend.

Comment: When you say different, they are not in reverse order by any chance?